# Pulsar Teclas Del Teclado

Tags: c#

Intento `pulsar una tecla del teclado` en C# con `código` pero no se como se puede lograr esto yo en varias ocasiones intentado poder lograr esto pero sin éxito sino es posible que tal en C++ yo escuchado que se comunica de manera mas directa con la maquina.

**¿Existe alguna forma de poder realizar lo que deseo lograr?**

Comment: pero cual es el objetivo de presionar la tecla? quieres realizar la accion en la propia aplicacion c# o en una de terceros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mas simple de lo que parece, aunque no lo creas es posible controlar todo el sistema con la API de windows, dejo un simple ejemplo en C++ el cual mencionas, ya que C# no es de mi tipo...

Primero antes que nada todo dependerá a que quieres enviar el Mensaje (se le llama mensaje en windows enviar un comando ya sea de tecla presionada o acción),
Ejemplo: Tu tienes ventanas, el cual esas ventanas tienen ventanas el cual le podemos llamar subventanas, el cual esas subventanas pueden ser controles,

Ejemplo con un bloc de notas:

```
// Obtenemos el handle de la ventana principal por el titulo de la ventana:

HWND handx = FindWindow(NULL, L"Sin título: Bloc de notas");

// ok, ahora obtenemos el handle del control EDIT, el cual es que usamos en el bloc de notas (gracias al handle padre o handle principal que obtuvimos anteriormente), si hay mas de uno de acuerdo a la documentación en MSDN se obtendrá el primero que se encuentre,
// Clase Edit del estándar de microsoft, ya que no sabemos el nombre de la ventana pero si el nombre del control...
HWND handy = FindWindowEx(handx, NULL, L"Edit", NULL);

// ok, Procedemos a enviar el mensaje,

 // ingresamos el handle, el tipo de key/evento dependiendo, se pueden enviar hasta las keys del sistema, en este caso envió la key F1, en lparam sería el scan code, pero no es necesario por ahora...

PostMessage(handy, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F1, 0);

// ahora enviaré una key tipo char de acuerdo a la tabla ascii
// En este caso 0x41 el cual es el numero 65 en decimal el cual corresponde a la A mayúscula en la tabla ascii..

PostMessage(handy, WM_CHAR, 0x41, 0);
```

Puedes probarlo, el cual quedaría:

```
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{    
    HWND handx = FindWindow(NULL, L"Sin título: Bloc de notas");

    HWND handy = FindWindowEx(handx, NULL, L"Edit", NULL);

    PostMessage(handy, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F1, 0);

    PostMessage(handy, WM_CHAR, 0x41, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo Tuve que escribir una linea para poder realizar Todo esta operación en C#

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```